# Define a function to choose 2 bigger number out of 3 numbers then sum the square of the 2 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Define a function that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

For example, given 6,7,8, the function that I defined should return 113

When I gave my code, it solves most of the problems but apparently there is some possibility that I haven't tried?? I think my code is flawed but not sure what other possibilities are there. Would really appreciate some help thank you so much!

```
def bigger_sum(a,b,c):
    if(a+b>b+c):
        return(a*a+b*b)
    if(a+c>b+c):
        return(a*a+c*c)
    if(b+c>a+c):
        return(b*b+c*c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min` for this problem:

```
def big2_sqrsum(a,b,c):
    x = min(a,b,c)
    return (a*a + b*b + c*c) - (x*x)

print(big2_sqrsum(6,7,8))
```

Output:

```
113
```

**Alternate solution with if-else**

```
def big2_sqrsum2(a,b,c):
    if a < b and a <c:
        return b*b + c*c
    elif b < a and b < c:
        return a*a + c*c
    elif c < a and c < b:
        return a*a + b*b
```

Comment: ooo clever! but I think that's besides the point of the exercise ;P. Pretty sure they are learning conditionnal statements, which your solution avoids. That said, this is the most effective code for that problem.

Comment: I added alternate solution too if OP wants the solution using `if-else`

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the smallest number. That known, assign the values to two new variables that will hold the largest and second largest value and sum their squares.

Something like this :

```
big1 = 0
big2 = 0

if ([a is smallest]):
    big1 = b
    big2 = c

elif ([b is smallest]):
    big1 = a
    big2 = c

elif ([c is smallest]):
    big1 = a
    big2 = b
```

allows you to have only one place to calculate your formula :

```
return big1 * big1 + big2 * big2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at why your code is flawed. Given a comparison like `if a + b > b + c:`, the implication that both `a` and `b` are both greater than `c` is false. `b` can be the smallest number. All you know is that `a > c`, since you can subtract `b` from both sides of the inequality.

You need to find and discard the smallest number. The simplest way is to compute the minimum with `min` and subtract it off, as [@Sociopath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320027/2988730) suggests.

If you want to keep your `if-else`structure, you have to compare numbers individually:

```
if a > b:
    n1= a
    n2 = b if b > c else c
elif a > c:
    n1, n2 = a, b
else:
    n1, n2 = b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can Simply Define Function With Using min()**

```
 def two_bigger_sum(num1,num2,num3):
    min_num = min(num1,num2,num3) # it returns minimum number
    return ((num1**2 + num2**2 + num3**2)-(min_num**2)) # num**2 = square of num


print(two_bigger_sum(6,7,8))
```

## Output = 113

Answer (score 1):

Sociopath's answer works, but is inefficient since it requires two extra floating point multiplies.  If you're doing this for a large number of items, it will take twice as long!  Instead, you can find the two largest numbers directly.  Basically, we're sorting the list and taking the two largest, this can be directly as follows:

```
def sumsquare(a,b,c):
    # Strategy: swap, and make sure c is the smallest by the end
    if c > b:
        b, c = c, b
    if c > a:
        a, c = c, a
    return a**2 + b**2

# Test:
print(sumsquare(3,1,2))
print(sumsquare(3,2,1))
print(sumsquare(1,2,3))
print(sumsquare(1,3,2))
print(sumsquare(2,1,3))
print(sumsquare(2,3,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to use list comprehension & list slicing with sorting method.

```
def b2(l):
    return sum([x**2 for x in sorted(l)[1:]])

print(b2([1,2,3]))
```

OP:-

```
13
```